# Update MS Word Template Dynamically using C#

Tags: c#, word-interop

I've added the Bookmark at particular position and save that file with .dotx. When I run the solutions, it add the date in the Template file but lost all the remaining records store in the template. 
I want to add the data in the Work template dynamically, and data can be grow it varies.

```
object oMissing = Missing.Value;
string DateParameter = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString();

Word._Application word = new Word.Application();
word.Visible = false;

// Template
object oTemplate = @"..\SampleTemplate.dotx";
Word._Document document = word.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

object oBookMark = "DateParameter";

Word.Range wrdRng = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(oBookMark).Range;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = document.Content;

rng.Text = DateParameter;

document.SaveAs2("TestDocument" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

GC.Collect();
```

Thank you

Comment: You should save the file as docx if it ceases to be a template once you have added the date.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the wrong Range.Text. 
In your code you are replacing the rng object instead of the wrdRng object which refers to the actual bookmark.

Try this:

```
 Word.Range wrdRng = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(oBookMark).Range;
 --Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = document.Content;

 wrdRng.Text = DateParameter;
```